# Extract the value stored using JMES path

Tags: jmespath

I need to extract the value stored in "$"
Due to several special characters in between, I am unable to do so. Can someone share a JMES path for this? Below is the JSON Code for your reference.

```
{
  "Body": {
      "{data:com.test/ee}Submit_Response": {
          "@{data:com.test/ee}ver": "v00.6",
          "{data:com.test/ee}ID_Reference": {
              "@{data:com.test/ee}Description": "(Inactive)",
              "{data:com.test/ee}ID": [{
                      "@{data:com.test/ee}type": "Test",
                      "$": "1c02asdasdasd02"
                  },
                  {
                      "@{data:com.test/ee}type": "ID",
                      "$": "T-15645"
                  }
              ]
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your json sample is invalid; try the following on your actual json and see if it works: `*|[1].*[]["$"]|[]` or `*.*[][]["$"][]`.

Comment: @JackFleeting I have corrected the JSON structure. The above suggestion doesn't seem to work, I am receiving a null response when using the above path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated json in the question is pretty convoluted, but you can get to your targets in a couple of ways, none of which is intuitive...

The terse versions:

```
*.*[][].*[].*[][].["$"][]
*.*.*.*[][][][]["$"][]
```

If you want to be a little more explicit, you can try:

```
Body.*[][].*[].*[][].["$"][]
Body.*.*.*[][][][]["$"][]
Body.*.["{data:com.test/ee}ID_Reference"][]["{data:com.test/ee}ID"][][]["$"][]
```

All of which output:

```
[
  "1c02asdasdasd02",
  "T-15645"
]
```

Comment: This helped, a slight addition/tweak in your approach *.*.*.*[][][][]["$"][]|[1] helped extracting the exact output.